# Merge 2 columns into DateTime not working

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge column TIME and DATE into into one single column Datetime and tell pandas to convert that into a datetime object. But I always get this error back... Thanks for help

```
File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser.py", line 559, in parse
raise ValueError("Unknown string format")

ValueError: Unknown string format
```

My code

```
from __future__ import print_function   
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import datetime                         

train_end=24                            
N=24

data1 = pd.read_csv('C:\XXX\XXX\XXX/GBPUSD.csv', 
header=None) 
data1.columns=['Date', 'Time', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Volume']
data1.shape

data1.head()                              

data1['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data1['Date'] + ' ' + data1['Time'])
```

Comment: Without a sample of the data you're working with there's no way anyone will be able to help you.

Comment: got it, here is the link to the file https://drive.google.com/open?id=12wATPb1QhdV-Zp45uYrUn-m5abvNH2-4

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark:

```
data1['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data1['Date'].astype(str) + ' ' + data1['Time'].astype(str))
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code (starting from `data1 = pd.read_csv...`) on the linked file and it worked perfectly: no exception, and the new column is present and correct. I tried mangling one of the dates and got the same exception you're getting. In whatever data file you're getting the error from, something must be wrong with at least one of the Date or Time entries.

I suggest trying to find the problem data and see if it's something you can fix automatically or something you need to just skip. Something like this may help:

```
In [18]: for index, row in data1.iterrows():
    ...:     try:
    ...:         pd.to_datetime(row['Date'] + ' ' + row['Time'])
    ...:     except ValueError:
    ...:         print(row)
Date      01/2a/2018
Time           01:30
Open         1.42279
High           1.423
Low          1.42182
Close        1.42195
Volume          1790
Name: 7, dtype: object
```

In this example you can see that the Date column has an "a" where it should have a number.

Comment: Thanks, i checked again the file before and after importing it and there are numbers in all rows, its very strange error. Could it related to python version?